# Sub that inserts the word Winner into Column O

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to inserts the word Winner into Column O when user selects the word Jackpot from a drop down list

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    For x = 6 To 88
        If Cells(x, 14).Value = "Jackpot" Then
            Cells(x, 15).Value = "Winnner"
        ElseIf Cells(x, 14).Value <> "High" Then 
            Cells(x, 15).Value = " "
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is when column O is populated by the user with any text the procedure should not overwrite the text entry.

I do not know how to write a VBA code that keeps the text entry the same and not have the procedure overwrite it.

Comment: Worksheet_SelectionChange mean that everytime you click everywhere in the sheet, the macro run, and everything going to be replaced. For let the macro do not change value changed by user, you have to identify that value with something, example, if its not empty that cell and its not Something, then that mean that someone changed it

Answer (score 1):

The event macro you are looking for is [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx), not the [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event macro.

The Worksheet_Change is triggered whenever any value on the worksheet changes (but not by a formula) so if you are going to use the Sub to change the values in column O, you need to temporarily suspend event handling while you make the changes or you risk having the Worksheet_Change try to run on top of itself.

When a change on the worksheet triggers the Worksheet_Change, you need to determine if the **Target** (the cell or cells that received the change) are in the range of cells that you are concerned with. This is done with the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx). In the following, one or more of the cells in Target have to be in column N between rows 6 and 88. If there are one or more then a [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) is used to loop through each cell that meets the criteria.

Each matching cell has it's value checked in sequence. The [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) takes care of multiple possible outcomes easily.

Put all of the points discussed above together and you should end up with code like the following.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(14), Range("6:88")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim win As Range
        For Each win In Intersect(Target, Columns(14), Range("6:88"))
            Select Case LCase(win.Value2)
                Case "jackpot"
                    win.Offset(0, 1) = "Winnner"  '<~~ ?? spelling...??
                Case "high"
                    ' do nothing...?
                Case Else
                    win.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End Select
        Next win
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've added the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of the code sheet¹. This will require you to declare your variables before using them.

I'm seeing N6:N88 populated with Data Validation drop-down lists.

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

Comment: Well explained answer!

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you use an activeX control combolist then you can assign a macro to it that will run on "Update"

check this

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     If ComboBox1.Value = "JackPot" Then
         Range("o1").Offset(0, 1).Value = "Winner"
     End If
 End Sub


 Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
      With Me.ComboBox1
          .AddItem "JackPot"
          .AddItem "high"
      End With
 End Sub
```

the offset is wrong but i went somewhere else with it at first.... should be easy enough for you to figure out form there

Comment: technically offset isnt needed, I was just being fancier than necessary. you can just straight up declare cell value